# JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: java, gwt

I have a web application which uses GWT 2.2 and Java 1.5 and is running on an Websphere Application Server 6.1.

It runs fine on Firefox (5.0.1) but on Internet Explorer 7 I get the following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object doesn't support this property or method
 number: -2146827850
```

Stack trace:

```
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FocusImplStandard.createFocusable0(FocusImplStandard.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FocusImplStandard.createFocusable(FocusImplStandard.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar.init(MenuBar.java:1086)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar.&lt;init&gt;(MenuBar.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar.&lt;init&gt;(MenuBar.java:213)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox$SuggestionMenu.&lt;init&gt;(SuggestBox.java:563)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox$DefaultSuggestionDisplay.&lt;init&gt;(SuggestBox.java:320)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.&lt;init&gt;(SuggestBox.java:723)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.&lt;init&gt;(SuggestBox.java:711)
    at com.estimation.web.client.ui.EnterEstimationDataView.createSuggestBox(EnterEstimationDataView.java:287)
    at com.estimation.web.client.ui.EnterEstimationDataView_EnterEstimationDataViewUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(EnterEstimationDataView_EnterEstimationDataViewUiBinderImpl.java:19)
    at com.estimation.web.client.ui.EnterEstimationDataView_EnterEstimationDataViewUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(EnterEstimationDataView_EnterEstimationDataViewUiBinderImpl.java:1)
    at com.estimation.web.client.ui.EnterEstimationDataView.&lt;init&gt;(EnterEstimationDataView.java:292)
    at com.estimation.web.client.ClientFactoryImpl.&lt;clinit&gt;(ClientFactoryImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
...
```

Stack Trace is from Dev Mode, but I assume the same happens in production mode as the IE does not display anything and shows a little yellow warning sign in the status bar.

I tried to comment out the part where the exception is thrown but then the same exception is thrown somewhere else.

From the different widgets which throw the exception it seems they are all focusable because this line was in every stack trace (last call before GWT starts doing native Java Script stuff):

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.FocusImplStandard.createFocusable(FocusImplStandard.java:65)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Does your project contain any custom, native Javascript code?  It could be this code which is causing the error.

Comment: No, it doesn't contain any native Javascript code. Apparently just the missing user agent lead to this error

Comment: Re _"Would be nice tough if at least the Dev Mode Plugin would realize that the correct permutation was missing..."_ newer version of GWT should notify you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging through forum posts, I realized I was missing the user.agent value for IE in the modul.gwt.xml `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6, gecko1_8" />` Without it IE tried to use another permutation, which was of course not compatible.

Would be nice tough if at least the Dev Mode Plugin would realize that the correct permutation was missing...